# Why does AND statement placement affect record count

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK so my question is: There a difference in record count depending on where the AND statement is positioned within my query. For instance, if I have several INNER JOINS and a couple LEFT Joins and at the very end of my query if I place all my AND statements the record count is different then if I place my AND statement right below the matching JOIN table. Since the AND statement specifies the table, why would it matter where its placed within the query?

Example 1:

```
FROM table (nolock)
INNER JOIN table2 (nolock) ON Table.ID = table2.ID
INNER JOIN table3 (nolock) ON table2.ID = table3.ID
LEFT JOIN table4 (nolock) ON table3.ID = table4.ID
where table.vendor = 1234
AND table.Active = 1
And table2.Active = 1
And table3.Active = 1
and table4.Active = 1
and table3.Name LIKE 'someName'
```

Example 2:

```
FROM table (nolock)

INNER JOIN table2 (nolock) ON Table.ID = table2.ID
And table2.Active = 1
INNER JOIN table3 (nolock) ON table2.ID = table3.ID
And table3.Active = 1
and table3.Name LIKE 'someName'
LEFT JOIN table4 (nolock) ON table3.ID = table4.ID
where table.vendor = 1234
and table4.Active = 1
AND table.Active = 1
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. Optimizer moves all `ON` predicates to `WHERE` for `INNER JOIN` before execution.

Comment: The conditions in your logic are different.  For instance, the second snippet is missing `table4.Name LIKE 'someName'`.

Comment: Can you write actually "equivalent" queries? (or at least, the conditions you are using). `FROM table AND table.Active = 1`?, that doesn't makes sense. And in the first example you use `and table4.Name LIKE 'someName'`, and the second uses and `table3.Name LIKE 'someName'`. PLease, take the time to write the correct queries

Comment: Also you are littering your queries with the NOLOCK hint and worried about accuracy. Are aware that hint can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows? Additionally omitting the WITH keyword is deprecated. If you are going to use table hints make sure you include WITH. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: To pile on with @SeanLange - [Bad habits: Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: I updated the query to the one im actually working on. If I move all the AND statements to the bottom of the query, it will give me a different record count then if I place the AND statements under each corresponding JOIN statement.

Comment: When you specify a condition in the where clause you are effectively changing the join to an inner join.

Comment: @SeanLange You are correct, of course, but the conditions used in the `LEFT JOIN` in this particular query isn't being moved to the `WHERE`, so I think that both queries should be equivalent (at least, the 2 queries that are currently written in the question)

Comment: @Lamak they are. In one query it is "And table2.Active = 1" in the where clause but in the other query that predicate is in the join clause.

Comment: Oh those are inner joins though....back to the coffee machine for a second....brb,

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, but `table2` is being used in an `INNER JOIN`. Oops, sorry, late response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `INNER JOIN` it makes no difference whether the criteria accompanies the `JOIN` or if it's in the  `WHERE` clause, however with `LEFT JOIN` adding join criteria doesn't filter out non-joining records, but that criteria in the `WHERE` clause will exclude non-joining records.  In your  case `WHERE table4.Active = 1` excludes non-joining records from table4, but moving that criteria to the `JOIN` will not exclude those records.

Here is a simple demonstration:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48910/2/1)

Note: I've made the assumption that your sample code isn't quite right and that this is the problem based on your description.

Comment: There's a detail in your answer that's not necessarily true. "with `LEFT JOIN` adding join criteria doesn't reduce the number of records returned", adding join criteria can reduce the number of rows returned if, for instance, there are duplicated rows with the first join conditions

Comment: @lamak Updated the wording, does it seem more clear?

Comment: It does, at least to me

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. In my query I didnt touch the WHERE statement but rather moved the AND statements from the end of the query to under each JOIN statement. So my question isn't rather about the WHERE statement but why would record count change depending where you would position the AND statement within the query

Comment: @goodfella Each `AND` is just adding criteria to either `JOIN` criteria or the `WHERE` clause.  So by moving the `AND` you are altering both. I've altered the example to show a single `AND` line moving, if that's helpful.

Comment: @GoatCO so for best practices, write the AND statements after each corresponding JOIN statement?